# Can Naive Set Comprehension survive in multi-valued logic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic, multivalued-logic

If $\phi$ is a formula in which $x$ is not free, then: 
$(\exists x \ \forall y \ (y \in x \leftrightarrow\ \phi)) $ is an axiom.

This is the inconsistent Naive comprehension axiom.

> Is this a paradox limited to classical [binary valued] first order logic?

I mean is this still paradoxical in multi-valued logic.

The idea is that in multi-valued logic we can have different truth values for $y \in x$, one can in some sense understand the different truth values as difference in probability of membership of $y$ in $x$.

Lets interpret the formula $y \not \in x$ as there is non zero probability of $y$ not being an element of $x$, in other words the probability of $y$ being a member of $x$ is not 1.

According to this I see the paradox disappear!

The idea is that the asserted set $x$ cannot have probability of $x \in x$ being 1, and also cannot have probability of $x \not \in x$ being 1 for obvious reasons that derives the paradox in binary logic, but it can have intermediate truth value, like for example $0.5$ probability of being in itself (and of course of not being in itself). This way I don't see any problem.

Comment: Ok.  Now resolve the Burali-Forti paradox.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, Basically the same argument, if you have fuzzy ordinals, you can still have the set of all of them and its a fuzzy element of itself.

Comment: @WilliamElliot This is a fine question. There's a decent amount of work (and I'm preparing an answer mentioning this) on ways to salvage naive set theory, including through many-valued logic. Whether probability *specifically* is a good motivating idea is a more technical issue, but this question definitely does not deserve a negative response (and I've upvoted).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has (unsurprisingly) been a decent amount of work on ways to salvage naive set theory by weakening the underlying deductive system - many-valued logic being only one aspect of this. Briefly, the situation is "**yes**, naive set theory is salvageable, but **we have to be careful**."

> CAVEAT: I'm not an expert on nonclassical logics, so everything below reflects my limited understanding and quite possibly contains serious omissions or errors; however, I hope that it is still useful for giving a taste of the landscape.$^1$

---

[Richard White showed](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30227183) in 1979 that full comprehension is consistent in infinite-valued Lukasiewicz logic; this confirmed a conjecture of Skolem and extended previous work by Skolem, Chang, and Hay (and others). See also Thierry Libert's essay [Semantics for naive set theory in many-valued logics](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-5012-7_9), in the volume "The age of alternative logics." But developing this logic is quite nontrivial.

Another interesting paper here is da Costa's [On paraconsistent set theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44084177). This lives in the realm of *paraconsistent*, rather than *many-valued*, logic, but I think is still relevant to your question. Da Costa establishes the nontriviality of a family of paraconsistent set theories admitting full comprehension (which he introduced in earlier work) *relative to the consistency of Quine's NF*. This latter question of course is probably the most famous open$^2$ problem in the study of alternative set theories, so in retrospect I don't know how confident we should be in the nontriviality of da Costa's systems. Still, neat!

I'll finally mention Richard Hinton's more recent (= 1994) paper [Naive Set Theory with Extensionality in Partial Logic and in Paradoxical Logic](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1040609292), which studies both the many-valued and paraconsistent approaches simultaneously.

There is other work in this context as well, and searching for combinations of the terms (paraconsistent, many-valued, "naive set theory") is fairly fruitful.

---

On the other hand, it's worth noting that we have to be very careful - there are paradoxes more subtle than Russell's, which even survive naive retreats to paraconsistency. [Moh Shaw-Kwei](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2267648) for example presents a version of Curry's paradox, roughly as follows:

> Suppose we accept the rule $$p\rightarrow (p\rightarrow q)\implies p\rightarrow q.$$ Fix your favorite sentence $\varphi$ and let $$A=\{x: x\in x\rightarrow \varphi\}.$$ The definition of $A$ tells us that $$(*)\quad A\in A\leftrightarrow (A\in A\rightarrow \varphi);$$ the left-to-right part of $(*)$ and absorption then give us $$(\dagger)\quad A\in A\rightarrow\varphi.$$ But this combines with the right-to-left direction of $(*)$ to give us $$A\in A,$$ which fed into $(\dagger)$ gives us $\varphi$.

So naive comprehension trivializes everything, *even without* bringing negation into the picture, unless we drop a very mild hypothesis about how implication works. (Actually, Shaw-Kwei proved something somewhat stronger.) Libert's article cited above discusses this and the Lukasiewicz approach.

That is, **we cannot conclude that a nonclassical approach to naive comprehension is consistent simply by observing that Russell's paradox doesn't go through**.

---

$^1$A bit of a mixed metaphor, but I like [peaty scotch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peat#Scotland).

*$^2$OK fine, Holmes has presented a claimed consistency proof. However, my understanding is that it has not yet been fully vetted.*

Comment: There's a typo in your statement of absorption, right? It's hard to accept as written!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Whoops, just saw this, of course you're right - I omitted part of the rule. Interestingly, it seems that "rule of absorption" is used nonstandardly by Shah-Kwei here; since I don't know what it's actually called, I've not given it a name. Do you know what it is?

Comment: That makes more sense! I don't know a name for that rule, but it could be reasonable to call it "contraction", since it's the "internalized" version of the sequent calculus rule: from $p,p\vdash q$ conclude $p\vdash q$."

Comment: The book *Petr Hájek on Mathematical Fuzzy Logic* says that a serious gap was found in White's consistency proof by Terui and that (as of 2014) consistency of full comprehension in Łukasiewicz logic is still open. I don't know of any more recent results.

Comment: @JamesHanson Whoah, didn't know that! I think that would be a good candidate for a follow-up question (either here or at MO), that should definitely be clarified.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't know if it's actually published anywhere, and I don't think I'll be able to suss out the gap any time soon.

Comment: @NoahSchweber [Actually, Terui has a note detailing the issue.](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~terui/whitenew.pdf)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do we know if something smaller than an infinite-valued logic can preserve comprehension? For instance, if we just use something like three-valued Kleene logic, would that do? Has there been any research on this?

Comment: Looks like Skolem has studied this: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24489127 - apparently consistent except for some snag with quantifiers. (And is equality allowed?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but it seems to me that naive set theory with ordinary 2-value logic could avoid RP-like internal contradictions if you stick to mathematical theories with some specified underlying set(s) (e.g. the set of natural numbers $N$ in number theory) -- i.e. no arbitrary sets or objects are to be considered after these underlying sets are established.

Comment: You need to clarify this. I don't see a clear answer relating to the topic of this posting. But still you need to clarify this answer.

Comment: The topic was how naive set theory could survive. It seems to me to be alive and well in most math textbooks (perhaps more so than ZFC), e.g. in real analysis, group theory, combinatorics etc. where there are defined underlying sets/structures. RP is not an issue in these fields because they don't talk about arbitrary sets or objects.

Comment: Though I'm not so sure, but from what I remember is that MacLane once said that most of whats in ordinary mathematics is bounded Separation. I have the impression that this is what you are talking about, so it's not naive comprehension.